# ориентация фото при вызове камеры с помощью интента (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, камера, android-camera, exif

Всем привет!
Есть проблема, решения которой не нашел:
Требуется сделать фото и загрузить в ImageView.

Создаю интент с помощью MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE для вызова камеры и сохраняю фото на телефон. 
После того как кнопка фото была нажата, снимок сразу отображается с поворотом 90 градусов.

Пробовал использовать ExifInterface, но getAttributeInt всегда возвращает 0.

OnCreateView с кнопкой:

```
final Intent captureImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        boolean canTakePhoto = mPhotoFile != null &&
                captureImage.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null;
        mPhotoButton.setEnabled(canTakePhoto);

        mPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = getUri();
                captureImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

                List<ResolveInfo> cameraActivities = getActivity().getPackageManager()
                        .queryIntentActivities(captureImage,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

                for (ResolveInfo activity: cameraActivities){
                    getActivity().grantUriPermission(activity.activityInfo.packageName,
                            uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                }

                startActivityForResult(captureImage,REQUEST_PHOTO);
```

Обработка ответа результата:

```
}else if (requestCode == REQUEST_PHOTO){
            Uri uri = getUri();

            getActivity().revokeUriPermission(uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            updateCrime();
            updatePhotoView();
        }
```

Метод updatePhotoView:

```
private void updatePhotoView(){

        if (mPhotoFile == null || !mPhotoFile.exists()){
            mPhotoView.setImageDrawable(null);
        }else{

            Bitmap bitmap = PictureUtils.getScaledBitmap(
                    mPhotoFile.getPath(),widthPhotoView,heighPhotoView);
            mPhotoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

Класс PictureUtils в котором содержатся методы для сжатия Bitmap а также попыток развернуть изображение

```
public static Bitmap getScaledBitmap(String path, int destWidth, int destHeight) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        float srcWidth = options.outWidth;
        float srcHeight = options.outHeight;

        int inSampleSize = 1;
        if (srcHeight > destHeight || srcWidth > destWidth) {
            float heightScale = srcHeight / destHeight;
            float widthScale = srcWidth / destWidth;

            inSampleSize = Math.round(heightScale > widthScale ? heightScale : widthScale);
        }

        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

        int angle = getPictureDegree(path);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        bitmap = rotateBitmap(angle,bitmap);

        return bitmap;
    }

    private static int getPictureDegree(String path) {
        int degree = 0;
        int orientation = 0;
        try {
            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(path);

            orientation = exifInterface.
                    getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            switch (orientation){
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    degree = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    degree = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    degree = 270;
                    break;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return degree;
    }

    private static Bitmap rotateBitmap(int angle, Bitmap bitmap){
        Bitmap newBitmap = null;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);

        try{
            newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,
                    0,
                    0,
                    bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(),
                    matrix,
                    true);
        }catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
        }

        if (newBitmap == null){
            newBitmap = bitmap;
        }

        if (newBitmap != bitmap){
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
        return newBitmap;
    }
```

Если в методе getPictureDegree вручную возвращать int , то разворот картинки происходит, т.е. как говорил выше exifInterface.getAttributeInt всегда возвращает 0.

Помогите с решением.

```
}
```